# Storing result of date arithmetic in string

Tags: abap

The following code is supposed to subtract 10 days from a given date, store the result in a string variable and write it.

```
DATA str TYPE string.
DATA date TYPE d.

date = '20130418'. " 2013-04-18
str = date - 10.

WRITE str.
```

I would expect the output to be 2013-04-08 or at least an unformated 20130408. But the actual output is a quite mysterious number which doesn't make sense to me at all:

```
734967
```

Can someone explain me where this number comes from?

I already found a workaround (just put the result in another variable of type d and then assign this variable to the string), but I am still interested in an explanation for this strange result.

SAP_BASIS release is 702.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [conversion rules](http://help.sap.com/SAPHELP_470/Helpdata/EN/fc/eb3434358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm): For the substraction, the date is converted to the number of days since 01.01.0001 internally (source type date, target type I), then the arithmetics take place. IF the result is a date field, a conversion (source type I/Packed, target type D) back into the form YYYYMMDD is applied. However, the conversion I/Packed to string is defined differently - so the string contains the number of days between your result date and 01.01.0001.